# How to concat first, second, third and so on of multiple arraylists in java

Tags: java, arraylist

There are arraylists that i have and i simply want to concat items with respect to their indexes in their respective arrayList.  The rough code block below explains more of what i want to achieve. EDITED

```
List<String> list1 = new Arraylist<String>();
List<String> list2 = new Arraylist<String>();
List<String> list3 = new Arraylist<String>();

list1.add("list11");
list1.add("list12");
list1.add("list13");

list2.add("list21");
list2.add("list22");


list3.add("list31");
list3.add("list32");
list3.add("list33");
list3.add("list34");  


List<ArrayList<String>> container = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
container.add(list1);
container.add(list2);
container.add(list3);

List<String> finalList  = new Arraylist<String>();

void concatMax(container){

}

//result finalList contents
list11 list21 list31 //- first item
list12 list22 list32 //- second item
list13 ------ list33 //- third item
------ ------ list34 //- forth item


void concatMin(container){

}

 //result inalList contents
list11 list21 list31 //- first item
list12 list22 list32 //- second item
```

Comment: Your expected result doesn't make sense to me. You've put it in a table, but want it to be String concatenation?

Comment: you can not do with current method signature, you need to pass each  array list seperately (or) need to send the lengths of individual arraylist along with the combined arraylist

Comment: You're adding a `List<String>` to a `List<String>`, which won't work.

Comment: Are you looking for [AddAll?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: It seems you want a matrix of elements. Maybe you're looking for a `List<List<String>>`?

Answer (score 1):

<s>replace</s>

```
container.add(list1);
container.add(list2);
container.add(list3);
```

with

```
container.addAll(list1);
container.addAll(list2);
container.addAll(list3);
```

then container will be your expected finalList (At least that is what I think you mean)

EDIT:

max:

```
int max = 0;
for (ArrayList<String> l : container) max = Math.max(max, l.size());

for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    String s = "";
    for (ArrayList<String> l : container) {

        if (i < l.size) {
            s += l.get(i) + " ";
        } else {
             s += "------ ";
        }
    }
    finalList.add(s);
}
```

min:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (ArrayList<String> l : container) min = Math.min(min, l.size());

for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
    String s = "";
    for (ArrayList<String> l : container) {
        s += l.get(i) + " ";
    }
    finalList.add(s);
}
```

Comment: I am really sorry for the earlier post i have edited it and made the correction for the container Arraylist

Comment: do you want finalList to be also `List<ArrayList<String>>`?

Comment: I tried your code ivo beckers .. the finalList size shows 12 but expected finalList size is 4 . heres of the code http://codepad.org/xwumWHyH

Comment: I changed my answer. Try that one

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me what you are looking for is a `transpose()` function that work on list of list

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    list1.add("list11");
    list1.add("list12");
    list1.add("list13");

    list2.add("list21");
    list2.add("list22");

    list3.add("list31");
    list3.add("list32");
    list3.add("list33");
    list3.add("list34");

    List<List<String>> container = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    container.add(list1);
    container.add(list2);
    container.add(list3);

    printList(container);
    List<List<String>> transposed = transpose(container);
    printList(transposed);

}

private static void printList(List<List<String>> transposed) {
    for (List<String> list : transposed) {
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    System.out.println("---------------");
}

private static List<List<String>> transpose(List<List<String>> container) {
    List<List<String>> newList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    int max = getMax(container);
    int i = 0;
    for (List<String> list : container) {
        for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
            String string =j<list.size()?list.get(j):null;
            setList(i, string, getList(newList, j));
        }
        i++;
    }
    return newList;
}

private static int getMax(List<List<String>> container) {
    int max=0;
    for (List<String> list : container) {
        max = Math.max(list.size(), max);
    }
    return max;
}

private static void setList(int i, String string,
        List<String> newInnerList) {
    if (i >= newInnerList.size()) {
        newInnerList.add(string);
    } else {
        newInnerList.set(i, string);
    }
}

private static List<String> getList(List<List<String>> list, int j) {
    List<String> innerList;
    if (j >= list.size()) {
        innerList  = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(innerList);
    }else{
        innerList = list.get(j);
    }
    return innerList;
}
```

**Output**

```
[list11, list12, list13]
[list21, list22]
[list31, list32, list33, list34]
---------------
[list11, list21, list31]
[list12, list22, list32]
[list13, null, list33]
[null, null, list34]
---------------
```